# How can I run a javascript open/close menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I created a menu with a Jquery open/close `button` for the mobile version of my website. Now I can open and close my menu but only by touching the menu button, in fact, once it's opened, if I try to tap one section `li.horizontal` the menu remains opened and I should fix it in order to get the menu closed both using the same button and the `li.horizontal`. Besides, since I would need jQuery only for the menu I'd prefer to use plain JavaScript, also because Google Speed test suggests that.

Sorry for my bad english... Thank you in advance for your help :)

This below is my current code:

```html
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    
  //When btn is clicked
  $(".btn-responsive-menu").click(function() {
   $("#menu").toggleClass("show");
  
  });
    
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="btn-responsive-menu">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>
<section id="home">
<header>
<!-- i contenuti -->

<div id="menu" class="">

<ul>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#theatres_museums">theatres & museums</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#luxury_houses">luxury houses</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#retail">retail</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#hotels">hotels</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#yacht">yacht</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="#design">design</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="news.html">news</a></li>
<li class="horizontal"><a href="contacts.html">contacts</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you can provide the sample as an example at https://jsfiddle.net/ . In the javascript section you can also provide libs like jquery to get your code runnig for everyone who wants to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this click event to close the menu on li click

```
$('.horizontal').click(function(){
   $("#menu").removeClass("show");
   window.location = $(this).find(a).attr('href');
});
```

vanilla js

```
document.getElementsByClassName("horizontal")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
document.getElementById("menu").className.replace(/\bshow\b/,'');
 window.location = e.target.getAttribute("href")
});
```

Comment: Ok it works thank you very much!! Do you know if is there an easy way to get it using plain javascript?

Comment: if you don't plan on using jquery then you can easily convert this to javascript

Comment: Thank you for the vanilla js, the problem is that I don't know javascript haha so I'd need the whole code, to open the button... I mean this below to convert in JS

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){   
    
  //When btn is clicked
  $(".btn-responsive-menu").click(function() {
   $("#menu").toggleClass("show");
  
  });
    
    });

Comment: Do I need to add attribute on click?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.horizontal').click(function(event){
   $("#menu").removeClass("show");
   window.location = $(event.target).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: The code of the other answer it works, your code closes the menu but it ends up in a "undefined black page". Thank you anyways! Do you now if is there an easy way to get the same result using plain javascript?